# Meaning of symbol used for vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I found this problem:

> Let V be an F-vector space of finite dimension, and let S and T be subspaces of V. Prove that
>   $$ (S+T)^{o}=S^{o} \cap T^{o} $$

Question:

What's the meaning of the small circle when used as an "exponent" of a vector space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators

Comment: Did you just happen upon this handout, or was it for a class that supposedly covered what the notation means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, the exponent is a zero, and $S^0$ is the [annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space#Quotient_spaces_and_annihilators) of $S$, that is, the set of linear functionals $f \in V^*$ such that $f(s)= 0$ for all $s \in S$.